# enable cors on a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my application_controller.rb I have the following code

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
before_filter :init_headers

def init_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
end
end
```

I am also using the a chrome plugin Allow-Control-Allow-Origin 
when I am running the angularjs front end I am getting the following error. 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
`Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404`

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I'd *highly* recommend using the [**Rack-CORS gem**](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors).

Instead of messing around with your `ApplicationController`, you'll be able to run rules from your `config` settings.

It handles CORS from the middleware, so you'll be able to create app-wide rules as follows:

```
#config/application.rb
...
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
   allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
   end
end
...
```

Their documentation is very good and self explanatory.

--

In regards your error, the `404` code suggests that you're trying to access a resource which simply doesn't exist. Either the URL or the routes won't be picking up the request.

Comment: I have same problem.I am using Rack-CORS gem.I could get, create, update data from postman. I can also get, create data from my client side react app, but when I try to update data using patch I get error as `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404`.